# Using media queries on content loaded by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

Is there any possible way to use media queries on content loaded by AJAX? I'm using .load() to load a html snippet into the web page. It is a light box I created using CSS. The problem is that media queries don't seem to have any effect on it.

Once the movie has been clicked, a html snippet is loaded into the div "lightbox-target" and a lightbox appears up on the screen. The lightbox is styled using ".detail".

```
<div class="template actionmovies">
  <h1 class="name">Batman: The Dark Knight</h1>
  <h2 class="imdb">9/10</h2>
  <h3 class="rotten">94%</h3>
  <a class="lightbox" href="#The_Dark_Knight" name="The_Dark_Knight">
    <img src="images/darkknight.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>

<!-- the HTML snippets load inside this div -->
<div class="lightbox-target">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lightbox-target {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  height: 525px;
  width: 65vw;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -34vw;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #3D3D3D;
  z-index: 1001;
  padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a.lightbox-close {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

i:hover {
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.lightbox-target:target {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
  top: 0px;
}


@media all and (max-width: 1405px){
   .detail {
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     height: 500px;
     width: 60vw;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -34vw;
     border: 3px solid white;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
     -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
     transition: .5s ease-in-out;
     background-color: #3D3D3D;
     z-index: 1001;
     padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
     border-radius: 10px;
   }
}
```

Comment: What are "media queries" in this context? Give an example.

Comment: Show us the code. Maybe the newly injected content doesn't make a sufficient change to warrant the media queries to kick in.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 If you don't know, this question is not for you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I do know. I'm not convinced the OP does.

Comment: Content in the DOM is content in the DOM. Any CSS applied to that DOM should affect it if the selectors match or values from the CSS get inherited. Using jQuery.load to put it in the DOM won't make any difference.